# Prove that $a_n=1+\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} +...+ \frac{1}{n!}$ converges using the Cauchy criterion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Any tips on how to approach these kind of proof problems when a factorial is included?

Here is what I've tried,

> By the Cauchy criterion the sequence converges if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ satisfies 
>   \begin{align}|a_{n+p}-a_n|&=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}+...+\frac{1}{(n+p)!}\\&<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+2)}+...+\frac{1}{(n+p-1)}\end{align}
>   any ideas on how to continue from here if what i did is correct at all?

Comment: The ratio test will be much simpler to apply here.

Comment: Also, $$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \dotsc + \frac{1}{(n+p)!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} + \dotsc + \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)\cdot\dotsc\cdot(n+p)}\biggr) \leqslant \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\biggl(1 + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{(n+2)^2} + \dotsc + \frac{1}{(n+2)^{p-1}}\biggr) < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+2}}.$$

Comment: Some related past questions: [Proof that the series expansion for exp(1) is a Cauchy sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1210309) and [Sequence of partial sums of e in Q is a Cauchy sequence.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1794189). Found by searching for posts tagged by [e+cauchy-sequences](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cauchy-sequences+e) or [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac1%7Bn!%7D%24%2C%20cauchy&p=1).

Comment: is there like a reference i could look at for these kind of stuff?,i'm trying to get better at proving convergence by its definitions,every problem i face its solved by methods that i cant come up with even if i had all the time in the world to think.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

**HINT**: $n!>2^n$.

**More Hints**:

$|a_n-a_m|=|\frac{1}{(m+1)!}+\frac{1}{(m+2)!}+\ldots+\frac{1}{(n)!}|$

$ \le |\frac{1}{(2^{m+1})}+\frac{1}{(2^{m+2})}+\ldots +\frac{1}{(2^{n})}|$

Now use the fact that $|r|^n\to 0 $ when $|r|<1$

Comment: Any more doubts?You can consider accepting it then @OP

Answer (score 1):

Noting that
$$ n!\ge (n-1)n $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
|a_{n+p}-a_n|&=&\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n+p)!}\\
&\le&\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{(n+p-1)(n+p)}\\
&=&\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+p}\\
&\le&\frac{1}{n}.
\end{eqnarray}
...

Answer (score 0):

Without Cauchy:

$a_n$ is clearly increasing, and as

$$n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdots1\ge2^{n-1},$$

$$a_n=1+\frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} +...+ \frac{1}{n!}\le1+\frac11+\frac12+\cdots\frac1{2^{n-1}}=1+\frac{1-\frac1{2^n}}{1-\frac12}<3.$$